# Gradle Application plugin: Need to include src in distribution

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm using Gradle's application plugin to bundle up a runtime for my application that includes required libraries and shell scripts to launching.  This is all working fine with the following:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'application'

applicationName = "appName"
mainClassName = 'com.myApp.cli.ScriptRunner'

buildDir = "${System.properties['user.home']}/.myApp/build"
archivesBaseName = 'myApp'
version = "1.0"
group = 'myApp'

sourceSets {
  main {
    groovy {
      srcDir 'src/groovy'
      exclude '**/web/**'
    }
    java {
      srcDir 'src/java'
    }

  }
}

startScripts {
  classpath  = files('$APP_HOME/lib/*')
}


repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
  // dependencies omitted for brevity
}
```

I found [from here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) that I can use applicationDistribution to include additional files.  The problem I'm running into is how to tell it which files I need.  I tried the following thinking this was the right approach:

```
task copySrc(type:Copy) {
  from('src/groovy/com/myApp/receiver') {
    include '**/*.groovy'
  }
  into "$buildDir/src"
}

task createSrc {
  def src = file("$buildDir/src")
  outputs.dir src
  doLast {
    src.mkdirs()
    copySrc
  }
}

applicationDistribution.from(createSrc) {
  into "src"
}
```

However, I don't ever see copySrc getting called and I'm not even sure if that is possible.  Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  I can just call the copySrc from the applicationDistribution.

```
task copySrc(type:Copy) {
  from('src/groovy/com/myApp/receiver') {
    include '**/*.groovy'
  }
  into "$buildDir/src"
}

applicationDistribution.from(copySrc) {
  into "src"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit easier:

```
applicationDistribution.from("${rootProject.projectDir}/") {
    include "README.md", "LICENSE.md"
}
```

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/groovydoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/ApplicationPluginConvention.html